# Caret and dummy variables

Tags: r, r-caret

When calling the `train` function of the caret package, the data is automatically transformed so that all factor variables are turned into a set of dummy variables.

How can I prevent this behaviour? Is it possible to say to caret "don't transform factors into dummy variables"?

For example:

If I run the `rpart` algorithm on the `etitanic` data:

```
library(caret)
library(earth)
data(etitanic)

etitanic$survived[etitanic$survived==1] <- 'YES'
etitanic$survived[etitanic$survived!='YES'] <- 'NO'

model<-train(survived~., data=etitanic, method='rpart')
```

Then the final model produced looks like so:

```
> model$finalModel
n= 1046 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 1046 427 NO (0.5917782 0.4082218)  
   2) sexmale>=0.5 658 135 NO (0.7948328 0.2051672)  
     4) age>=9.5 615 110 NO (0.8211382 0.1788618) *
     5) age< 9.5 43  18 YES (0.4186047 0.5813953)  
      10) sibsp>=2.5 16   1 NO (0.9375000 0.0625000) *
      11) sibsp< 2.5 27   3 YES (0.1111111 0.8888889) *
   3) sexmale< 0.5 388  96 YES (0.2474227 0.7525773) *
```

whereas if I run the `rpart` algorithm directly and build a tree, I get

```
> rpart(survived~., data=etitanic)
n= 1046 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 1046 427 NO (0.59177820 0.40822180)  
   2) sex=male 658 135 NO (0.79483283 0.20516717)  
     4) age>=9.5 615 110 NO (0.82113821 0.17886179) *
     5) age< 9.5 43  18 YES (0.41860465 0.58139535)  
      10) sibsp>=2.5 16   1 NO (0.93750000 0.06250000) *
      11) sibsp< 2.5 27   3 YES (0.11111111 0.88888889) *
   3) sex=female 388  96 YES (0.24742268 0.75257732)  
     6) pclass=3rd 152  72 NO (0.52631579 0.47368421)  
      12) age>=1.5 145  66 NO (0.54482759 0.45517241)  
        24) sibsp>=1.5 19   4 NO (0.78947368 0.21052632) *
        25) sibsp< 1.5 126  62 NO (0.50793651 0.49206349)  
          50) age>=27.5 44  15 NO (0.65909091 0.34090909) *
          51) age< 27.5 82  35 YES (0.42682927 0.57317073) *
      13) age< 1.5 7   1 YES (0.14285714 0.85714286) *
     7) pclass=1st,2nd 236  16 YES (0.06779661 0.93220339) *
```

Now, forget the part that the trees are different. I understand, they are built with different parameters. However, they are also build on **different data sets**. For example, the caret tree was built on a dataset where one column was "sexmale", and this was the dummy column made from the `sex` column in the original data.

Is there some way to tell `caret` not to perform this dummy variable creation before feeding the data to `rpart`?

Comment: Unlikely that the algorithm will accept non-numeric variables, that is why factors/characters are encoded as dummy variables.

Comment: @iboboboru see my example. The `caret` package in my example calls a function that **is** able to handle factors. I want to know what I can do to make sure the factors make it to the internal call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make caret behave exactly like rpart first I set the `trainControl` function to "none" and will use a tuneGrid of one record with a cp setting of 0.01. The defaults are then exactly the same as the defaults of `rpart`.

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "none")
#caret formula model
model<-train(survived ~ ., 
             data=etitanic, 
             method='rpart', 
             trControl = ctrl, 
             tuneGrid = expand.grid(cp = 0.01))

# rpart model
model_rp <- rpart(survived~., data=etitanic)

print(model$finalModel)

 1) root 1046 427 NO (0.59177820 0.40822180)  
   2) sexmale>=0.5 658 135 NO (0.79483283 0.20516717)  
     4) age>=9.5 615 110 NO (0.82113821 0.17886179) *
     5) age< 9.5 43  18 YES (0.41860465 0.58139535)  
      10) sibsp>=2.5 16   1 NO (0.93750000 0.06250000) *
      11) sibsp< 2.5 27   3 YES (0.11111111 0.88888889) *
   3) sexmale< 0.5 388  96 YES (0.24742268 0.75257732)  
     6) pclass3rd>=0.5 152  72 NO (0.52631579 0.47368421)  
      12) age>=1.5 145  66 NO (0.54482759 0.45517241)  
        24) sibsp>=1.5 19   4 NO (0.78947368 0.21052632) *
        25) sibsp< 1.5 126  62 NO (0.50793651 0.49206349)  
          50) age>=27.5 44  15 NO (0.65909091 0.34090909) *
          51) age< 27.5 82  35 YES (0.42682927 0.57317073) *
      13) age< 1.5 7   1 YES (0.14285714 0.85714286) *
     7) pclass3rd< 0.5 236  16 YES (0.06779661 0.93220339) *

print(model_rp)


 1) root 1046 427 NO (0.59177820 0.40822180)  
   2) sex=male 658 135 NO (0.79483283 0.20516717)  
     4) age>=9.5 615 110 NO (0.82113821 0.17886179) *
     5) age< 9.5 43  18 YES (0.41860465 0.58139535)  
      10) sibsp>=2.5 16   1 NO (0.93750000 0.06250000) *
      11) sibsp< 2.5 27   3 YES (0.11111111 0.88888889) *
   3) sex=female 388  96 YES (0.24742268 0.75257732)  
     6) pclass=3rd 152  72 NO (0.52631579 0.47368421)  
      12) age>=1.5 145  66 NO (0.54482759 0.45517241)  
        24) sibsp>=1.5 19   4 NO (0.78947368 0.21052632) *
        25) sibsp< 1.5 126  62 NO (0.50793651 0.49206349)  
          50) age>=27.5 44  15 NO (0.65909091 0.34090909) *
          51) age< 27.5 82  35 YES (0.42682927 0.57317073) *
      13) age< 1.5 7   1 YES (0.14285714 0.85714286) *
     7) pclass=1st,2nd 236  16 YES (0.06779661 0.93220339) *
```

Looking at both models you can see that even though caret transformed the factors and characters to have a default class as areference class, the tree is exactly the same with the same percentages in the nodes. You could use the partykit package and use `as.party()` on the models to get a better layout.

But if you want to have the exact same model as rpart without using the factors, you can use the default way of using models.

```
#caret default model
model_xy <-train(x = etitanic[, -2], 
                 y = etitanic$survived, 
                 method='rpart', 
                 trControl = ctrl, 
                 tuneGrid = expand.grid(cp = 0.01))

print(model_xy$finalModel)

 1) root 1046 427 NO (0.59177820 0.40822180)  
   2) sex=male 658 135 NO (0.79483283 0.20516717)  
     4) age>=9.5 615 110 NO (0.82113821 0.17886179) *
     5) age< 9.5 43  18 YES (0.41860465 0.58139535)  
      10) sibsp>=2.5 16   1 NO (0.93750000 0.06250000) *
      11) sibsp< 2.5 27   3 YES (0.11111111 0.88888889) *
   3) sex=female 388  96 YES (0.24742268 0.75257732)  
     6) pclass=3rd 152  72 NO (0.52631579 0.47368421)  
      12) age>=1.5 145  66 NO (0.54482759 0.45517241)  
        24) sibsp>=1.5 19   4 NO (0.78947368 0.21052632) *
        25) sibsp< 1.5 126  62 NO (0.50793651 0.49206349)  
          50) age>=27.5 44  15 NO (0.65909091 0.34090909) *
          51) age< 27.5 82  35 YES (0.42682927 0.57317073) *
      13) age< 1.5 7   1 YES (0.14285714 0.85714286) *
     7) pclass=1st,2nd 236  16 YES (0.06779661 0.93220339) *
```